# React Native WebView status bar

Tags: react-native, webview, statusbar

How to fix this problem on WebView?

[react-webview-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5js.jpg)

My code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://foo.co' }} style={{ marginTop: 50 }} />;
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <>
       <StatusBar hidden={true} />                  
       <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://foo.co' }} style=     {{marginTop: 50 }} />
       </>;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's fix! Thanks, I would like to add a color but the param BackgroundColor doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: yes it works..  <StatusBar hidden={true}  backgroundColor: {'white'} barStyle={{}}  />

Comment: Yes, it's done, but BackgroundColor doesn't work for me. No changes.

Comment: My typo  :  as backgroundColor prop works for Android only and barStyle prop works only for iOS. 

 <StatusBar hidden={true} backgroundColor={'white'} barStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} />